# NameError: name 'randint' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
options = [ "Choice 1: 1-9", "Choice 2: 10- 100",  ]
button = buttonbox ( msg = "Choose your range of numbers", title = "Select number range", choices = options)

if button == "Choice 1: 1-9":
 from random import randint
rn1 = randint(30,50)
from random import randint
rn2 = randint(30,50)

options = [ "Close"]
buttonbox ( msg = "%s X %s = ___" % (rn1, rn2), title = "Select number range", choices = options)
if button == "Choice 2: 10- 100":
 from random import randint
rn2 = randint (10,100)
from random import randint
rn2 = randint (10,100)
options = [ "Close"]
buttonbox ( msg = "%s X %s = ___" % (rn1, rn2), title = "Select number range", choices = options)
```

This is my code, when I try and run the second choice, it says `NameError: name 'randint' is not defined` even though the code is exactly the same as the first option, but with different numbers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have `from random import randint` dependent on the user choice? why not just import it anyway? i.e. move that line above the `if` statements and have only one import statement

Comment: `import` statements are executable in Python, so only do something if part of the code path. This problem wouldn't have happened if you followed [PEP 8 - The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) where it suggests that "[Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants". Since your code is going to use `randint` one way or the other, you might as well get importing it out of the way and get rid of all the other redundancies.

Answer (score 7):

Only import randint once, at the top of the file. Put `from random import randint` at the top of the program and remove it in all other places. I think this is what you want:

```
from random import randint

options = ["Choice 1: 1-9", "Choice 2: 10- 100"]
button = buttonbox(msg="Choose your range of numbers", title="Select number range", choices=options)

if button == options[0]:
    rn1 = randint(30, 50)
    rn2 = randint(30, 50)

elif button == options[1]:
    rn1 = randint(10, 100)
    rn2 = randint(10, 100)

options = ["Close"]
buttonbox (msg="%s X %s = ___" % (rn1, rn2), title="Select number range", choices=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that button is not equal to "Choice 1: 1-9". It might have some trailing whitespaces or a new line charecter. Try printing it to verify that. You can remove those by using [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip).

In any case, as [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) mentioned, it is not recommended to have conditional imports. Even worse, you are importing the same module two lines down. I am not sure if you want do that, but I would suggest to put the rn1 definition in the check instead.

Comment: If you suspect something you should post a comment instead of proposing an answer, especially when the answer isn't in fact an answer.